# Proof of Paley-Zygmund inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The proof of the [Paley-Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality)  provided in the link just says that the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) was used but doesn't show the steps. I tried to read and understand the wiki article on Cauchy-Schwarz to derive Paley-Zygmund inequality but couldn't understand the below line:

> After defining an inner product on the set of random variables using
>   the expectation of their product, $X \cdot Y = E(XY)$

Can you please help me understand the meaning of inner product on the set of random variables? Any directions on how to derive the Paley-Zygmund inequality would also be helpful.

Comment: There aren't any steps to show; apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the inner product $(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}[XY]$ on the vector space of random variables (or similar object).

Comment: @anomaly, Thank you for the response. Does the inner product mean the sum of the product of possible values of the random variables X and Y?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space